# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created this custom React package: https://github.com/leongaban/leon-theme

`npm i leon-theme`

Next created a new basic create-react-app & installed styled-components

When I import this line into the new react app's index.js file I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/leon-theme/dist/index.js 7:21-44
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components' in '/Users/leongaban/Projects/test3/node_modules/leon-theme/dist'

What the custom package's compiled index.js looks like

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");
tslib_1.__exportStar(require("./components"), exports);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I downgraded `react-scripts` `"react-scripts": "^4.0.2"` but this didn't help.

At a loss atm, at first I was trying to solve a `process is missing` error, but just needed to install styled-components in the new react app. Now running into this Can't resolve error.

Package's tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "nodenext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Your `dist/components` directory doesn't have an `index.js` file (just `index.d.ts`). I would think for `require("./components")` to work, it would need an actual file

Comment: There is a dist/index file actually, I just fixed my issue btw, I needed to remove `"moduleResolution": "nodenext",` and convert `module` back to `es6` in the tsconfig

Comment: Nice. You should add an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at first I was getting errors with missing process.

I updated my react-scripts to the latest, which I then had to fix by lowering to `^4.0.2`, which actually resolved to `^4.0.3`

Next I also changed the `module` and `moduleResolution` keys both to `nodenext`

This was what caused the problem with missing components.

After I completely removed `moduleResolution` this solved my issue.